# JQuery UI button with hover/background

Tags: jquery, css

I got a JQuery UI button with an icon (locked) and I want it to switch to unlocked when I hover, I am pretty sure it's quite simple but after searching on Google I've found no doc/example about that. Here is my code

> $("#frmClients button.btnConnexion").button({
>               icons: {
>                   primary: 'ui-icon-locked'
>               },
>               text: true
>     });

And here  the documentation page of the UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a stab, but from the documentation, something like this might work:

```
$("#frmClients button.btnConnexion")
  .button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-locked' }, text: true })
  .hover(function() {
    $(this).button('option' , 'icons' , { primary: 'ui-icon-unlocked' });
  }, function() {
    $(this).button('option' , 'icons' , { primary: 'ui-icon-locked' });
  });
```

Comment: Hmm... any idea where it's failing? What happens if you throw in some alerts or console.logs inside the hover callbacks?

Comment: Well I think this is not a valid syntax for jquery ui, this code doesn't say when to show locked and when to show unlocked, I suppose the button only show the last one specified (locked).

Comment: Not sure why that's not working for you. I just ran that code snippet (with a different selector and without the first .button() call) over on the jQueryUI example page (http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/icons.html) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Haha, I've just copy/pasted the same code like I did yesterday...it works...guess it was an Error 17 (17inch in front of the monitor).

Thanks +1